# My page is not responsive when I run the with UWSGI

Tags: nginx, flask, chart.js, responsive, uwsgi

#### I wanted a realtime dashboard and I cloned this https://github.com/roniemartinez/real-time-charts-with-flask.git

I installed the requirements and the application runs normally and fine whenever I run with the "python application.py" command. The "/" route in the application run responsively and fine...

I added the app to a uwsgi ini file and when I run. the web page of the "/" becomes irresponsive and bring the graphs every 30seconds. All works fine with the application. but I think the problem is either my nginx config or uwsgi ini.

what could be wrong ?

```
[uwsgi]


base = /home/pi/Desktop/Bingo

app = application
module = %(app)

home = %(base)/venv
pythonpath = /home/pi/Desktop/Bingo/venv/bin/python

socket = /home/pi/Desktop/Bingo/%n.sock

chmod-socket    = 666

callable = app


logto = /home/pi/Desktop/Bingo/log/uwsgi/%n.log
```

#### My nginx config is

```
server {
    listen  80;
    server_name localhost;
    charset utf-8;
    client_max_body_size 75M;

    location /static {
    root /home/pi/Desktop/Bingo;
    }

    location / { try_files $uri @labapp;}
    location @labapp {
    include uwsgi_params;
    uwsgi_pass unix:/home/pi/Desktop/Bingo/lab_app_uwsgi.sock;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The `uwsgi` logs probably contain some useful clues. Comparing your `uwsgi.ini` to one of mine, I see a few differences that might be significant. First, I always `chdir` to the base of the app, which in your case would look like

```
[uwsgi]
chdir = /home/pi/Desktop/Bingo
home = /home/pi/Desktop/Bingo/venv
module = application:application
... socket
... log
```

I also wonder if might also have a mismatch, depending on how you've named things, between

```
socket = /home/pi/Desktop/Bingo/%n.sock
```

and

```
uwsgi_pass unix:/home/pi/Desktop/Bingo/lab_app_uwsgi.sock;
```

The nginx error log is the place to look.

(See https://github.com/davewsmith/nginx-uwsgi-flask-starter/blob/master/provision/starter.ini for a working example)

Comment: sorry I couldn't find anything with this ..I suppose the problem so from my uwsgi configs.....Do you observe anything that related to this